# Using DOM Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a xml using the below code,i am able to parse it and read the values.But i am not sure how to modify the code to read the node "INFO",i have escaped that node and directly using PARAM as below:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myxml>
  <id>23343</id>
  <INFO>
    <PARAM>
      <PARAM_NAME>data</PARAM_NAME>
      <PARAM_VALUE>345</PARAM_VALUE>
    </PARAM>
    <PARAM>
      <PARAM_NAME>CdataID</PARAM_NAME>
      <PARAM_VALUE>6788</PARAM_VALUE>
    </PARAM>
  </INFO>
</myxml>
```

and the java code is :

```
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

      NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("PARAM");

      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
          if (getTagValue("PARAM_NAME",eElement).equals("data")) {
            String type = getTagValue("PARAM_VALUE", eElement);
          } 
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }
}
```

I want to add INFO node ,how to modify the above code ?

Comment: The code above loops over the param nodes, but doesn't do anything with them. And your question is "how to add INFO node". But add what to what? What do you want to do with the INFO node?

Comment: Can you please add the output XML that you want to get after adding another INFO node?